# How to bind user's control label content to the custom dependency property

Tags: wpf, binding, dependency-properties

I'm trying to bind user's control label content to the custom dependency property. My dependency property is:

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty DayProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("Day", typeof(string), typeof(MultiSlider),   new UIPropertyMetadata("some"));

    public string Day
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(DayProperty); }
        set { SetValue(DayProperty, value); }
    }
```

I want to get something like

```
<Label Content="{TemplateBinding Day}"/>
```

inside of my user control.

Comment: You may post your solution as an answer and accept that. I guess that would improve the quality of this Q&A.

Comment: Clemens, thanks for advice. I couldn't do this because of small reputation value, now I have it enough :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved by adding:

```
DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"
```

to my user control and then just:

```
<Label Content="{Binding Path=Day}"/>
```